# CSS Drop Down Menu - Gaps between Drop down and Sub Menu, disappears in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am currently using a CSS menu on PHP includes. I have gotten to to be compatible with IE and Chrome and I assume Firefox. However in IE, The sub menu for my drop down menu is to far away from the drop down and disapears before I can hover above it.

The original CSS

```css
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 70px; background-color: rgb(35,35,35); box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}


#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: rgb(160,160,160);
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: rgb(250,250,250); }


#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}

#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
    font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}


#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}


#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}


#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(205,44,36);
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

MENU code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='about.php'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Services</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='4wdtraining.php'><span>4WD Training</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='basictraining.php'><span>Basic</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='intermediatetraining.php'><span>Intermediate</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='advancedtraining.php'><span>Advanced</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='nightdriving.php'><span>Night Driving</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='recovery.php'><span>Recovery</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='custompackages.php'><span>Custom Packages</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='bushmechanic.php'><span>Bush Mechanic</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='estore.php'><span>eStore</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='gallery.php'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Live example at www.offthebitumen.com.au
Things I have tried: Changing the padding, changing positions from absolute to relative, getting rid of the border, adding display: inline - nothing has worked.

Also if anyone has Chrome and IE, why is the menu more rounded compared to the IE version? Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a gap.

I did a little hack, hope it will help.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='about.php'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Services</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub '><a href='4wdtraining.php'><span>4WD Training</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='basictraining.php'><span>Basic</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='intermediatetraining.php'><span>Intermediate</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='advancedtraining.php'><span>Advanced</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='nightdriving.php'><span>Night Driving</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='recovery.php'><span>Recovery</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='custompackages.php'><span>Custom Packages</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- THIS IS THE FIX --> <div class="hack"></div> <!-- end FIX -->
         </li>
         <li><a href='bushmechanic.php'><span>Bush Mechanic</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='estore.php'><span>eStore</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='gallery.php'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And just 2 bits of css:

```
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
   z-index: 5;
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: No luck, it caused the menu buttons to go away with the additional coding? If there is a new div class #hack, should I modify to suit my CSS?

Comment: I've had to use a different menu, I just could not find an alternative, one way or another something would go wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a similar problem with www.agradedemo.com - I tried your solution on there as well but I haven't had any luck. Any ideas?